# Unable to receive SSDP response packets when SSDP discovery packet is sent - Scapy

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, ssdp

I am using Scapy to create an SSDP protocol discovery packet for all devices (ssdp:all) however suddenly I am not getting any response from the devices when I did get them before. I am using a Ubuntu VM. This is the code I am using to create the packet.

```
ssdpPacket = IP(dst="239.255.255.250")/UDP(sport=6700,dport=1900)/Raw(load='M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMAN:"ssdp:discover"\r\nMX: 2\r\n\r\n')
send(ssdpPacket)
```

In wireshark, I see that it does send the packet but no response. I am kind of frustrated because it worked before and now its just not working. Help!!